# Multiple conditions in select query using Oracle 11g

Tags: vb.net, oracle, select, multiple-columns, where-clause

I have a table and I'm trying to run query with multiple conditions

```
select POLICY_REFER,
       END_REFER,
       CLIENT_NAME,
       POLICY_PRODUCT,
       ISSUE_DATE,
       GROSS,
       DOC_TYPE,
       DOC_STATUS
from   POLICY_MASTER
```

1. ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN: DFrom AND: DTo
2. DOC_STATUS = 'Parked'

These two condition are must match the

3. CLIENT_NAME =:Client or CLIENT_NAME is null
4. POLICY_PRODUCT =:Product or POLICY_PRODUCT is null

These two are depend on selection from combo box, for which I write this

```
select POLICY_REFER,
       END_REFER,
       CLIENT_NAME,
       POLICY_PRODUCT,
       ISSUE_DATE,
       GROSS,
       DOC_TYPE,
       DOC_STATUS
from   POLICY_MASTER
where  ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN :DFrom AND :DTo
and    CLIENT_NAME = :Client or CLIENT_NAME is null
and    POLICY_PRODUCT = :Product or POLICY_PRODUCT is null
and    DOC_STATUS = 'Parked'"....
```

This query can accept  POLICY_PRODUCT is null but not working with CLIENT_NAME is null...

Comment: You probably need to use some parentheses in your `WHERE` clause. In Boolean logic, `AND` takes precedence over `OR` so, unless you want all `AND` operators evaluated from left to right first and then all `OR` operators evaluated from left to right afterwards, you need to use parentheses to specify the order of evaluation.

Comment: jmcilhinney , ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN :DFrom AND :DTo  ......must entered               DOC_STATUS = 'Parked' .... is fixed                                                                                   CLIENT_NAME   & POLICY_PRODUCT are optional parameters maybe have  value maybe null (null mean here all ) , can you write a query for me, please

Comment: You can do an optional parameter like so: `(:Param IS NULL OR Column = :PARAM)`.  You then set the `Value` of the parameter to `DBNull.Value` in your VB code if you want that parameter effectively ignored.

Comment: can you please explain how i can dbnull.value in this code             cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = CmbProduct.Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you are missing brackets around your `or` conditions, e.g. I think your query should be something along the lines of:

```
select POLICY_REFER,
       END_REFER,
       CLIENT_NAME,
       POLICY_PRODUCT,
       ISSUE_DATE,
       GROSS,
       DOC_TYPE,
       DOC_STATUS
from   POLICY_MASTER
where  ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN :DFrom AND :DTo
and    (CLIENT_NAME = :client or :client is null)
and    (POLICY_PRODUCT = :product or :product is null)
and    DOC_STATUS = 'Parked'"....
```

Comment: Boneist , your query not working as required ....ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN :DFrom AND :DTo ......must entered,      DOC_STATUS = 'Parked' .... is fixed CLIENT_NAME & POLICY_PRODUCT are optional parameters maybe have value maybe null (null mean here all ) , can you write a query for me, please

Comment: Explain what you mean by "not working as required", please.

Comment: Oh, I see; the :client and :product parameters can be null, and you want to return all results if they are null? Then you need to have `or :client is null` etc. I have updated my answer.

Comment: your query working perfect on SQL developer but not in vb.net , why , vb.net says "all variable not bound"

Comment: You would need to raise this as a new question which contains the vb you're using to call the query.

Answer (score 0):

> Query seems to working fine. I think the problem is with the
>   attributes of the column CLIENT_NAME, check whether the  attributes of
>   the column, because there are attributes that doesn't allow null
>   values in a query

```
select POLICY_REFER,
       END_REFER,
       CLIENT_NAME,
       POLICY_PRODUCT,
       ISSUE_DATE,
       GROSS,
       DOC_TYPE,
       DOC_STATUS
from   POLICY_MASTER
where  (ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN :DFrom AND :DTo)
and    (CLIENT_NAME = :Client or CLIENT_NAME is null)
and    (POLICY_PRODUCT = :Product or POLICY_PRODUCT is null)
and    DOC_STATUS = 'Parked'"
```

Comment: MunishGowtham Baskaran    , your query not working as required ....ISSUE_DATE BETWEEN :DFrom AND :DTo ......must entered,      DOC_STATUS = 'Parked' .... is fixed CLIENT_NAME & POLICY_PRODUCT are optional parameters maybe have value maybe null (null mean here all ) , can you write a query for me, please